# Which one is the better query plan?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 
    MAX(HORA_LEIT), ST_BOMBA, Q_BOMBA, SEQUENCIAL 
FROM 
    DADOS 
WHERE 
    COD_PONTO = 2085 
    AND (ST_BOMBA = 'ON' OR ST_BOMBA = 'OFF') 
GROUP BY 
    ST_BOMBA, Q_BOMBA, SEQUENCIAL 
ORDER BY 
    MAX(HORA_LEIT) DESC
```

I decided to create two indexes:

```sql
CREATE INDEX ix_1 
ON dados (cod_ponto, St_bomba) 
INCLUDE (q_bomba, sequencial, hora_leit) 
WHERE St_bomba IN ('ON', 'OFF')
```

Actual execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkxiKmDXs

and

```sql
CREATE INDEX ix_2 
ON dados (cod_ponto, hora_leit) 
INCLUDE (St_bomba, q_bomba, sequencial) 
WHERE St_bomba IN ('ON', 'OFF')
```

Actual execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=By_1tmDQj

I figured out, as far as I can see, that the first execution plan is better, although the query optimizer is giving preference to the second one.

Am I misevaluating the performance?

Comment: Why do you think plan #1 is better? #1 : subtree cost 0.18059, memory grant = 1024 - while plan #2 has subtree cost of 0.0032833 and no memory grant .....

Comment: This query, using the second index, has compile time over 1100 in production environment, I'm trying to find alternatives. @marc_s

Comment: Is there a better index to cover this query? @marc_s

Comment: I thought that having >75k estimated number of rows to be read was terrible.

Comment: @BookWritter Please keep all relevant questions concisely written together in your original Post. I've never heard of using the `Estimated Number of Rows to be Read` as a metric worthwhile for using for performance tuning. Personally I think it's a rather arbitrary metric as long as your cardinality estimates match your actuals close enough (they're spot on in your second plan) and the `Actual Number of Rows Read` isn't unnecessarily high (which it isn't). Please see my answer for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ix_2` is clearly better.

The first thing to note is that the query is written in a very convoluted way.

The query

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    MAX(HORA_LEIT), ST_BOMBA, Q_BOMBA, SEQUENCIAL 
FROM 
    DADOS 
WHERE 
    COD_PONTO = 2085 
    AND (ST_BOMBA = 'ON' OR ST_BOMBA = 'OFF') 
GROUP BY 
    ST_BOMBA, Q_BOMBA, SEQUENCIAL 
ORDER BY 
    MAX(HORA_LEIT) DESC
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    HORA_LEIT, ST_BOMBA, Q_BOMBA, SEQUENCIAL 
FROM 
    DADOS 
WHERE 
    COD_PONTO = 2085 
    AND (ST_BOMBA = 'ON' OR ST_BOMBA = 'OFF') 
ORDER BY 
    HORA_LEIT DESC
```

As you are only interested in the `TOP 1` the `GROUP BY` can be optimized out here.

> Side note this may not be immediately apparent why but...
>
> Take a row with the highest `HORA_LEIT` in the table (matching the where conditions). This is going to be in a group at least tied for first place when ordered by `MAX(HORA_LEIT) DESC`.
>
> So taking the `ST_BOMBA, Q_BOMBA, SEQUENCIAL` from that row is going to produce the values for a valid group that satisfies the initial query. If different rows have the same `HORA_LEIT` equalling the `MAX` but different `ST_BOMBA, Q_BOMBA, SEQUENCIAL` then it is undeterminstic which one you get in both versions of the query.

Both execution plans recognize this and don't contain any aggregation operators.

For index 2 the filtered index condition guarantees that all rows match the `ST_BOMBA` condition. It just has to do a backward ordered index seek on `COD_PONTO = 2085` and read the first row and then stop (as the second key column is `HORA_LEIT`).

For index 1 the index seek is actually two seeks.

- seek on `(COD_PONTO, ST_BOMBA)` = `(2085, 'ON')`
- seek on `(COD_PONTO, ST_BOMBA)` = `(2085, 'OFF')`

The combined rows matching either of those conditions then go into the Top N sort to get the TOP 1 matching row as ordered by `HORA_LEIT DESC`. It is only 96 rows in this case but is potentially unbounded and just depends on your data.

Reading a single row and stopping is better than reading an arbitrary number of rows and sorting them.

Comment: "is equivalent to"  This is only true when the combination of `ST_BOMBA, Q_BOMBA, SEQUENCIAL` is unique, which might not be the case ?

Comment: @Luuk no it doesn't require that. Think about what group the top 1 row will end up in and how that will be ordered

Comment: I am am not convinced, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/JhPEoat-

Comment: You've put in a load of ties so it is undeterministic which `TOP 1` you get. There are four groups with `MAX(HORA_LEIT)` of `3`. The result from your query 4 is an equally correct answer. Any of the rows returned from Query 3 are correct https://dbfiddle.uk/dOFiqK7E

Comment: If this was not a valid transformation the query execution plans wouldn't do it

Comment: [Because the order of rows stored in a table is unspecified, the SELECT TOP statement is always used in conjunction with the ORDER BY clause. Therefore, the result set is limited to the first N number of ordered rows.](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-select-top/)   There is not order specified for `Q_BOMBA`, results from first and second query are not the same. => ?

Comment: Take a row with the highest `HORA_LEIT` in the table. This is going to be in a group at least tied for first place when ordered by `MAX(HORA_LEIT) DESC`. So taking the `ST_BOMBA, Q_BOMBA, SEQUENCIAL` from that row is going to produce the values for a valid group that satisfies the query

Comment: If you use `TOP 1` with a non deterministic `ORDER BY` clause there are multiple possible "right" answers. The query transformation is correct

Answer (score 1):

Aside from marc said in the comments, the second query plan only has to seek into 1 row in the index (`Actual Number of Rows`) and has a perfect cardinality estimate then because it also estimated 1 row.

The first execution plan estimates around 250 rows but actually seeks into 95 rows on the index, so slightly less efficient and a worse cardinality estimate.

But to be honest, for such a simple query plan and small amount of data, you might find the best way to compare is by looking at the [`TIME STATISTICS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [`IO STATISTICS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-io-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). E.g. run `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;` first, then run each query that produces each plan above and compare. The results will be in the Messages window in SSMS.

`TIME STATISTICS` will give you the Parse and Compile Time of the query (which shouldn't be super relevant for this test) and the total CPU and Elapsed Time.

`IO STATISTICS` will tell you how many data pages were read from Memory (the Logical Reads) to serve your query.

The plan that required less of either or both is *generally* better.

---

> Is there a better index to cover this query?

You may want to try the index on `(COD_PONTO, ST_BOMBA, Q_BOMBA, SEQUENCIAL, HORA_LEIT DESC) WHERE ST_BOMBA IN ('ON', 'OFF')` which will cover all of the fields in your query, or possibly `(COD_PONTO, ST_BOMBA, HORA_LEIT DESC, Q_BOMBA, SEQUENCIAL) WHERE ST_BOMBA IN ('ON', 'OFF')`. *Generally* (but not always) indexing by your predicates (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, `HAVING` clauses) first is most advantageous, then by the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses next. But definitely test and compare, that's the only way to be sure.

Comment: The index ix_2 is already the optimal one for the query. It does an index seek that reads and returns 0 or 1 row and then stops. This is already the minimal amount of work that can be done to return the required result.

Comment: @MartinSmith Heh yeah, most likely can't do better than that, other than minute differences in runtime. But it's such a simple plan, it's doubtful, maybe equal at best.